# What are the subsequetial limits of an enumeration of rational numbers?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

So my question is if we have an enumertaion of rational numbers considered as a sequence, is there a subsequence converging to every real number. I think this is the case since we can find a rational sequence approaching the real number. But I am not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 1):

Pick a real number $x$.

Let $a_1$ be any element of the enumerated rationals other than (possibly) $x$.

Choose $a_2$ beyond $a_1$ satisfying $0 < |x-a_2| < \frac 12 |x-a_1|$. This is possible because there are infinitely many such terms.

Then choose $a_3$ beyond $a_2$ satisfying $0 < |x-a_3| < \frac 12 |x-a_2|$.

I think it is clear how to continue.